# Microsoft Azure DevOps Pipeline failing with Connection Reset error in Gradle Android

Tags: android, azure, gradle, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I am running my CI pipeline in MS Azure DevOps and the pipeline always fails with the same error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':feature-onboarding:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':feature-onboarding:DebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not download okio-1.17.4.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:1.17.4)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.17.4/okio-1.17.4.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.17.4/okio-1.17.4.jar'.
            > Connection reset
```

I have tried multiple approaches:

1. Increase ram size to 8GB
2. Adding extra properties to gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout=300000
org.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout=300000
org.gradle.internal.repository.max.retries=10
org.gradle.internal.repository.initial.backoff=500
```

3. Running with macOS-10.15, macOS-10.14, macOS-latest
4. Running gradleW without daemon

Extra:
Unit Test Template used:

```
parameters:
  gradleCommand: 'testDebugUnitTest'

steps:
  - task: Gradle@2
    displayName: 'Run Tests'
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: ''
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx8192m'
      publishJUnitResults: false
      testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
      tasks: '${{ parameters.gradleCommand }} --no-daemon --no-parallel --stacktrace'
```

But none of them seem to work and the error still persists.
How can we fix this issue?

Comment: We started to get similar errors. If we run the build on a self hosted agent everything works fine. Did you manage to find the cause of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it is relevant- try not use the JCenter, not before Maven Central

Jfrog leaves gradually JCenter and it cause problems, especially to the Azure DevOps pipelines.

I changed the order of the repository to check first the Maven Central and only then JCenter and it resolved the problem.

https://onesignal.com/blog/android-migrate-jcenter-to-maven-central/

Comment: Please add an explanation of your recommendation. Note that the content found at the link is not considered part of your answer here.